# Codeanywhere: backup on Android

Tags: android, backup, codeanywhere

I'm trying to use [codeanywhere](http://codeanywhere.com)'s app to do some coding on my android phone while on the road. It works fine except I'd like to make backups of my files and can't figure out a way. My attempts:

- Download files and folders from the app. There is an option to do this in a `...` menu but it doesn't work; it takes me to a blank page where nothing happens
- Through scp. This is only possible using an ssh key, and I couldn't find an easy to use android app for scp with keys instead of password.
- By connecting to github. After reading [this](https://blog.skilstak.io/why-we-left-codeanywhere-com-2f29b229a768) I decided to create a new github account for this purpose. However I can't figure out how to set up a new repository on android. Also this seems a bit elaborate just to take backups of a toy project..

Any ideas? Or suggestions for other ways to do on the road coding (I'm writing in Haskell)?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem: downloading files / folders works from the website (not the app)